# Combinational Problem: Find how many ways 24 students can be assign in 3 groups.

Tags: permutations, combinations

I have 3 problems about this combinational problem.

I have 24 students.

**1.** Firstly, In how many ways we can assign 24 students in 3 groups if the first group has 14 students, second group 6 and third group 4?

**My Αnswer:**

> $$ \binom{24}{14} \cdot \binom{10}{6} \cdot \binom{4}{4} = 411863760. $$

---

**2.** Secondly, In how many ways we can assign 24 students in 3 groups if each group has 8 students?

**My Αnswer:**

> $$ \frac{\binom{24}{8} \cdot \binom{16}{8} \cdot \binom{8}{8}}{3!} = 1577585295. $$

---

**3.** Thirdly, In how many ways we can assign 24 students in 3 groups if the first group has 14 students, second group 5 and third group 5?

**My Αnswer:**

> $$ \binom{24}{14} \cdot \frac{\binom{10}{5} \cdot \binom{5}{5}}{2!} = 247118256. $$

---

**4.** Finally, In how many ways we can assign 24 students in 3 groups if the first group has 14 students, second group 5 and third group 5 BUT the first group is named RED, the second GREEN and the third BLUE?

**My Αnswer:**

> $$ \binom{24}{14} \cdot \binom{10}{5} \cdot \binom{5}{5} = 494236512. $$

---

Comment: All of the above is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your confirmation !

Comment: What is the difference between calling the groups "first, second, and third" and calling them "RED, GREEN, and BLUE"?

Comment: I not quite sure about that, it's an exercise I found but I think it's suppose to tell me that 14 students are specific and I cannot place them in the second group or something like this, but again I didn't get a clear response about this from my professor. In the other questions you can assume all students are RED for example. There is no difference for calling the groups first, second and third I am just stating how the first group will be shaped and we go on..

Comment: The underlying issue is whether the groups are distinguishable or not: with "first, second, and third" and "RED, GREEN, and BLUE," they are identified, hence distinguishable. With "one of the groups, another group, and the remaining group," they are interchangeable.

Comment: That's why I didn't divide question 4 with 2! Do you think that's correct then?